# apply pie command to data in matlab

Tags: matlab, charts, pie-chart

following simple declaration

```
grade=[11 18 26 9 5];
pie(grade)
```

gives me following simple pie chart
    [image]

but i want to  make pie diagram from this  structure

```
 product(1).name='hp';
>> product(1).price=200;
>> product(2).name='hp';
>> product(2).price=1200;
>> product(2).name='apple';
>> product(3).name='dell';
>> product(3).price=600;
>> product(4).name='Toshiba';
>> product(4).price=700;
```

when i have applied,i have got

```
pie(product)
Undefined function 'le' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in pie (line 35)
nonpositive = (x <= 0);
```

so how could i fix it?please help me,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pie()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pie.html) takes a matrix as input, not a struct array, so you need to extract the struct fields you want into a matrix. Luckily, this is very simple, since [`<structarray>.<field>` returns a list of data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) that we can capture in a concatenation operator. This works for cell arrays too, so let's generate labels at the same time:

```
pie([product.price], {product.name});
```

Comment: thanks very much,but it does not show percentages,how could i fix it?